# Make CasperJS talk to parent process

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I'm using [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/index.html) to test my web application and I'm running Casper's instance from the parent Node.js process using `require('child_process').spawn`.

I find myself in situation, where I need to pause Casper's execution after several steps and give control back to parent program in order to perform some actions and then pass some additional data from parent process to the Casper and proceed with the next steps.

Is it possible to achieve this?

---

Actually, I need to perform some HTTP (POST) requests between some steps, but it looks like I can't do this from Casper's environment, I need full-fledged Node.js support.

Comment: I won't make an official answer because I'm not sure if I get your question 100% but look up for SpookyJS. It makes the bridge between node and casper. You can pass info with function tuples and ultimately you can just json encode - decode what you need.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I've tried to use it, but looks like it's not properly maintained for some time. It's just not working with latest versions of Node.js, Casper and Phantom.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`__utils__.sendAJAX`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax) from the page context (`casper.evaluate(..)`)?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I need to send a screenshot of the page via HTTP, probably I will not be able to do this from the page context.

Comment: Yes, it's tricky to get the binary encoding right with `base64encode(fs.read(filename))`.